# Is this plumbing repair sound?

Tags: plumbing, repair, copper

I opened up a wall as part of a project and discovered some obviously newer pieces of copper pipe on one of the water supply lines. The drywall shows evidence of water stains as does the drywall and doors on the floor below. There must have been a leak in the pipe that was subsequently repaired (before I bought the house).

Looking at the repaired water line, I don't see any solder - it looks as if the new pieces are just crimped on. Is this an acceptable way of repairing a leak in copper, or should I be worried about it leaking in the future?

[image: Overall view]

[image: Close up]

Comment: These seem to be called press-fit fittings.

Answer (score 2):

These are copper press fit connectors. They have "o"rings installed at each end of the connector.

[image]

Once the connectors are in place, they are crimped with a special, and expensive, tool. They are supposed to be as good as sweating and Sharkbite connectors but they are not reusable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those fittings are crimped on with a very expensive machine and are good if done properly.

If not done well they leak straight away and I had to have the plumber come back to do a few on stainless pipe...